# Can't not downcast in java at runtime

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class Animal and a class Dog as following:

```
  class Animal{}
  class Dog extend Animal{}
```

And the main class:

```
   class Test{
       public static void main(String[] args){
           Animal a= new Animal();
           Dog dog = (Dog)a;
       }
   }
```

error is show:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Animal cannot be cast to com.example.Dog
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An animal could not be a dog can be a cat or something else like in your case an Animal

```
Animal a= new Animal(); // a points in heap to Animal object
Dog dog = (Dog)a; // A dog is an animal but not all animals are  dog
```

For downcasting you have to do this

```
Animal a = new Dog();
Dog dog = (Dog)a;
```

By the way, downcasting is dangerous you can have this `RuntimeException` , if it's for training purpose it's ok.

If you want to avoid runtime exceptions you can do this check but it'll be a little more slower.

```
 Animal a = new Dog();
 Dog dog = null;
  if(a instanceof Dog){
    dog = (Dog)a;
  }
```