# Why does "ClassCastException" occur in my code?

Tags: java

```
interface Foo {}
class Alpha implements Foo {}
class Beta extends Alpha {}

class Delta extends Beta {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Beta x = new Beta();
        Foo f=(Delta) x; 
    }
}
```

Why does `ClassCastException` occur here?

Comment: Because not every `Animal` is a `Dog`, this is only true the other way around.

Comment: a Delta is a Beta but a Beta is not necessarily a Delta.

Comment: see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499281/cant-not-downcast-in-java-at-runtime/17499286#17499286) here

Answer (score 6):

Just wrote your code in Simple English:

Foo

Alpha **IS-A** Foo

Beta **IS-A** Alpha

Delta **IS-A** Beta

## NOTE:

Beta **IS-NOT** A Delta

Change the line here;

```
Foo f = (Delta) x;
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving a `ClassCastException` in accordance with [JLS §5.5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.3):

> Here is the algorithm to check whether the run-time type `R` of an object is assignment compatible with the type `T` which is the erasure ([§4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)) of the type named in the cast operator. If a run-time exception is thrown, it is a `ClassCastException`.
>
> If `R` is an ordinary class (not an array class):
>
> - **If `T` is a class type, then `R` must be either the same class ([§4.3.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.4)) as `T` or a subclass of `T`, or a run-time exception is thrown.**
> - ...
>
> ...

In your case, `R` is `Beta` and `T` is `Delta`. Notice that `Beta` is not a subclass of `Delta`.

Answer (score 1):

You're casting `x` as `Delta` but `x` is of type `Beta`, which is extended by `Delta` and not vice-versa. Hence, your `ClassCastException`.

By the way, what happened to *Gamma*?