# Can we assign parent class object to a child class variable in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, runtime

I'm a beginner in Java and I was playing with some Java code. However I couldn't sort out why is it giving runtime error when I assign the reference of a parent class object to a child class variable. I've done explicit typecasting too. Is there any way possible to resolve it?

```java
class Employee{
    int e;//creating empty class
}

class Teacher extends Employee{
    int f;//creating empty class
}

class run{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Employee e;
        e= new Employee();
        Teacher t;
        t= (Teacher)e; //giving runtime error
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answers your question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145767/why-cant-reference-to-child-class-object-refer-to-the-parent-class-object/12972331>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't not downcast in java at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499281/cant-not-downcast-in-java-at-runtime)

Comment: Downcasting cannot be implicit

Answer (score 3):

A `Teacher` is an `Employee`, but not every `Employee` is a `Teacher`.

So, an `Employee` variable can hold objects of type `Employee` itself, as well as its subclasses like `Teacher`, `Worker` or whatever. But if you have a `Teacher` variable, it can only hold `Teacher` instances (and subclasses of `Teacher`), but not `Employee` or `Worker` instances.

With

```
t = (Teacher) e;
```

you have `e`, an `Employee` variable. Generally, this `e` does not "fit into" a `Teacher` variable, only in the possible case that the `Employee` variable `e` holds an `Employee` subclass instance, namely a `Teacher` instance.

So, without the cast, the compiler forbids the assignment. Writing the cast, you as developer tell the compiler

> Hey, I know that generally the assignment isn't allowed, but I promise
> that, at runtime, the instance in `e` will be a `Teacher`. So, please
> compile that line of code despite the risk, and give me an exception
> at runtime if my promise doesn't hold.

And that's what happens.

Answer (score 2):

We can assign child class object to parent class reference variable but we can't assign parent class object to child class reference variable.